# Add identical string to each element, passed as function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if (something1 == true) SomeFunction('a:link', 'a:visited', 'a:hover, a:focus, a:active');
```

What's the clever way to add `*` after each element? That's mean;

```
else (something2 == true) SomeFunction('a:link *', 'a:visited *', 'a:hover *, a:focus *, a:active *');
```

Comment: Your question is presently very unclear. Please state clearly what you're trying to acheive, what you've tried, and what problems you're facing.

Comment: @Utkanos I want somehow automatically add `*` after `a:link`, `a:visited`, `a:hover`, `a:focus` and `a:active`. No problems if my question is downvoted. I understand, it's not my best.

Comment: Just edit the question. Help us to help you. What do you mean function parameter? To what function? How is the string passed in? Does it live in the DOM? You haven't given us any wider, contextual details of what you're trying to do, that's all.

Comment: it's unclear because it makes no sense to "add" something to a parameter. You might want to add something to their values _inside the function_

Comment: Is this requirement to modify the args in this way common enough that it should be the responsibility of `SomeFunction` to perform the change instead of the caller, based on passing `condition` to it?

Comment: @Alnitak Hm. I should think about it more. I do my JS projects on weekends, as hobby. My current knowledge is a bit limited to completely understand your comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ES6:

```
let args = ['a:link', 'a:visited', 'a:hover', 'a:focus', 'a:active'];
let modifiedArgs = args.map((arg) => arg + ' *');
if (condition) SomeFunction(...args);
else SomeFunction(...modifiedArgs);
```

Comment: Thank you. It's exactly what I searched for.